# how to loop through objects in react app and display in renders return statement

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, javascript-objects

I know there are alot of posts out there similar, but none have helped me specifically.

I have this object:

```
   const people = {
    "John": {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Smith",
      "age": 41,
      "phone": "0401555666"
    },
    "Jack": {
      "firstname": "Jack",
      "lastname": "Williams",
      "age": 43,
      "phone": "0401777888"
    }
  }
```

I've added this to the component state:

```
this.state = { people, };
```

What I want to achieve is in the components render() methods return() statement is to write the people and their details to an unordered list.

- John

  - firstname: John
  - lastname: Smith
  - age: 41
  - phone: 0401555666
- Jack

  - firstname: Jack
  - lastname: Williams
  - age:43
  - phone: 0401777888

The people can change so I can't directly reference the individual people using something like:

```
Object.entries(this.state.people.John)
```

It doesn't look like I can use a for loop in the render() methods return() statement.  So really I have 2 requirements, neither of which I can achieve.  The first is simply to loop through the object.  The other problem I'm having is doing this in the render() return() statement, and writing it to a list.

In the render() method outside the return() statement I've tried this:

```
const myPeople = Object.entries(this.state.people);
console.log("My People: " + myPeople);
```

The result I get is this:

```
My People: John,[object Object],Jack,[object Object]
```

If I use the below in the return() statement:

```
{Object.entries(this.state.people)}
```

I get this error in the browser:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {firstname, lastname, age, phone}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I also tried this in the render() method outside the return() statement:

```
const a = Object.entries(this.state.people).map(x => console.log(x))
```

This started looking better in the console:
[console.log.jpg (image)][1]

But when I tried using it in the render() methods return() statement like this:

```
{Object.entries(this.state.people).map(x => <ul><li>{x}</li></ul>)}
```

I get a familiar error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {firstname, lastname, age, phone}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

The only way I get can it to work, which doesn't really help me as I would have to know the names in advance.  I can get those names with:

```
Object.keys(this.state.people)
```

but I'm not sure how to use that to my advantage.  I've tried a few things, all with no luck.  For example:

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.state.people);
const myPeople = keys.map(x => this.state.people.x)
console.log("My People: " + myPeople)
```

and this:

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.state.people);
for (let key of keys) {
console.log("My People: " + this.state.people.key)
}
```

But both these return:

```
My People: ,
```

So as you can see, I'm really stuck and have been for many hours, and even if I can figure out the correct way to loop through the object, I still won't know how to use the values in the render() methods return() statement. Also I don't want to use jquery $('#id').append(...) to write to the dom.

Please help me, maybe I'm really stupid but no other post will help me, i've tried, so sorry if the answer is out there, I didn't find it.  What I found is not 100% exactly this.

Comment: For dynamic key you should do this - `this.state.people[key]` and `this.state.people[x]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
const people = {
    "John": {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "age": 41,
        "phone": "0401555666"
    },
    "Jack": {
        "firstname": "Jack",
        "lastname": "Williams",
        "age": 43,
        "phone": "0401777888"
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                {Object.entries(people).map(item => (
                    <li key={item[0]}>
                        {item[0]}:
                        <ul>
                            {Object.entries(item[1]).map(subItem => (
                                <li key={subItem[0]}>
                                    {subItem[0]}: {subItem[1]}
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}
```

Put `people` object outside `render()` method if it's dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have objects within an object, you can iterate trough it with a loop within a loop, using `Object.entries`.

This is what you want:

```
<ul>
  {Object.entries(people).map([key, value] => (
    <li key={key}>
      {key}
      <ul>
        {Object.entries(value).map([subKey, subValue] => (
          <li key={subKey}>
            {subKey}: {subValue}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(people).forEach(function (key) { 
    console.log(people[key]); 
}
```

Loop over the object like this.

Answer (score 0):

You were really close with Object.keys solution.
Only thing you have to change is:

```
const myPeople = keys.map(x => this.state.people[x])
```

If you use x without array accessor ('[]'), you'd try to get a field call x, which is undefined. But you want to access x's value as a field key.